# i want the nav buttons to appear below the logo in the mobile view with auto centering

Tags: html, css, media-queries

HTML CODE WRITTEN FOR DESKTOP VIEW

```
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
    <header>
        <div class="header-logo"></div>
            <nav class="nav clearfix">
                <ul> 
                <li><a class="active" href="#">LOGIN</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS CODE WRITTEN FOR DESKTOP VIEW

```
 header{
        position: fixed;
        top:0px;
        width: 100%;
        height:80px;
        background-color:#0165ba;
        font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
        margin: 0 auto;
         display: block;
    }


    .header-logo

    {
     width:20%;
     background-image: url("/images/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:80px; 
    float:left;
    }

    .nav{

     width:80%;
     height:80px;
     float:right;

    }
    .nav a{
        color: #fff; 
        text-decoration: none;
        display:inline-block;
        height: 50px;
        width:120px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 56px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-left: 4px;
    }
    .nav ul{
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;

    }
    .nav li {
      float:right;
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      line-height: 80px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .nav a.active {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #0165ba;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .nav a:hover{
      background-color: #fff;
      color:#0165ba; 
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .nav a.active:hover {
      background-color:#0165ba;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

[image: The header is displayed lIke this:]

[image: I want the Header to be displayed like this when i write a media query for mobile view]

The first is the header i have written i want it to make it like the image below that,  i have tried but couldn't make it like that.

I currently getting the following output with the code below that.
[image]

css code i have written for movile view

```
header{
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#0165ba;
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.header-logo

{
 width:30%;
 height: 53px;
 background-position: center;
 background-image: url("/images/logo-small.png");
 height:70px;
    float:left;
}

.nav{
 width:70%;
 background-color:#0165ba;
 float: right;

}
.nav a{
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width:60px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
.nav ul,li{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;   

}
.nav li,ul {
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0165ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav a:hover{
  background-color: #fff;
  color:#0165ba; 
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.nav a.active:hover {
  background-color:#0165ba;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: So what is it doing wrong?

Comment: i have updated the question withe the code i have written for the mobile view and the output i am currently getting

Comment: Thanks i have corrected the code and got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the floats for `.header-logo` and `.nav` on the mobile CSS and add `margin:0 auto;` to whatever you want to be aligned.

I've also made a few changes, check out the whole CSS code and also online example below:
 http://jsfiddle.net/tv5k14yr/

```
header{
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#0165ba;
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
.header-logo{
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(http://listography.com/action/list-image?uid=9739888104&lid=6819615378);
    height: 70px;
}
.nav{
    background-color: #0165ba;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;        
}
.nav a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
.nav ul,li{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;

}
.nav li,ul {
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.nav a.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #0165ba;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.nav a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#0165ba; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.nav a.active:hover {
    background-color:#0165ba;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @user2218550 . If you have some time to spare, please consider marking my answer as correct ;)